# How to modify the code `legal` in order to add some more lines to the items

Tags: enumerate, itemize

Hi I want to add some lines in this code in order to have something like this:

### First item ------------------------------------------------------------------------

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

(lines to fill)

### Second item

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

```
This is the code that I found in this forum:
    \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\newcommand{\xfill}[2][1ex]{{%
  \dimen0=#2\advance\dimen0 by #1
  \leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth -#1\hfill%
}}
\newlist{mylegal}{enumerate}{1}
\newif\iffirstlegal\firstlegalfalse% We need a toggle to track whether the item is first in the list or not
\setlist[mylegal]{%
  label=\arabic*.,
  before*={% This saves the standard definition of \item and then redefines it to add the fill if the item is not first on the list; if it is the first item, it omits the fill but toggles the firstlegal switch so the next item will trigger it
    \let\olditem\item% save the standard definition of \item in a macro, \olditem
    \firstlegaltrue% set the toggle for first item in the list to true
    \def\item{\iffirstlegal\olditem\firstlegalfalse\else \xfill{.5pt}\mbox{}\olditem\fi}% new, temporary defition of \item
    },
  after*={% This takes care of adding the fill for the final item on the list and just makes sure that \item is reset to its standard definition
    \xfill{.5pt}\mbox{}% fill for final item in list
       \let\item\olditem% restore standard definition of \item
    }%
  }
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: How many lines would you like to add for each item? A constant number of lines for every item or can the number of lines vary?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please always add full code in the form of [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Thank all of you for your answers. Actually I would like to have two codes: one with 6 lines and other with the double. I would like to be able to understand it and modify by my self. Next time I will add the full code and read the starter guide ;-)

Comment: Are you trying to make a question paper with space for answers?

Comment: yes, but usig numerate environement because I have a lot of questions. Like this : 
1) question
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2) question
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Then you may better use `exam` class.

Comment: Can you make an exemple just for one question and having the space to answer the question?

Comment: Thank you very much @Harish Kumar !!!! this is perfect and what i need it ! thank you all very much for your time ! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your intentions, it is easy if you use `exam` class.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question
    In no more than one paragraph, explain why the earth is round.
    \fillwithlines{1.5in}
    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part
        What changes to the van Allen radiation belt are needed to make
        the earth into a regular icosahedron?
        \fillwithlines{3in}
        \part
        Where should the field generator be constructed if you want one of
        the vertices to be located at the Royal Observatory at Greenwich?
        \fillwithlines{1in}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thee are many other advantages like printing the answers.

For customizing the lines, read the following part of the manual (`texdoc exam` from terminal/command prompt)

[image]